# Where are the French help files?

Tags: help-system

Background: I'm an english-speaking, francophone student. In an effort to improve my vocabulary, my MacBook has been running in French since January, when I arrived in France. Incidentally, this means that `$LANG=fr_FR.utf-8`. I was able to get ahold of the spell files.

I decided it would be nice if I had access to vim help in french. `:help help-translated` points to [the translations page](http://www.vim.org/translations.php), which points us to this [website](http://vim.dindinx.net/).

Unfortunately, Safari reports it "can't find the server."

A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/?q=vim+french+help+files) didn't turn up anything useful either.

I did find [this translation from 2017](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/8gL01Udn8E8/i4pk_Oi4CAAJ), but it appears to be the error messages only and is not a drop-in bundle of help files per `:help` itself--it appears it may have to be compiled in?

**Question**: Where are the vim help files in French? Do they still exist? If not, will someone get them back online so I can use them? (I would gladly put them in a GitHub repo somewhere so they persist for eternity).

Here is the [relevant post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/RLrs0XJxfa4/9t9wg-MsCgAJ) on the `vim_dev` mailing list.

---

*N.B.* `vimtutor fr` works just fine.

Comment: I remember about a translation... Ages ago. You should ask the question on vim_dev mailing list, you'll be more likely to run onto people that know, or used to know about it.

Comment: Good suggestion @LucHermitte will do

Comment: I have set up a workbase to update the translation. https://framagit.org/fabienhinault/vimhelp-fr . Not sure that I'll have time/energy to make it all, thought.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I thought gettext was supposed to auto-generate translated help files in other languages. Is it that it doesn't support French or is gettext not incorporated in vim (i.e., I knew wrong)?

Comment: @kadekai gettext is used for error messages and similar. The help files are maintained manually or not at all IIRC. possibly they are generated though.

Answer (score 4):

The answer, for the moment, seems to be:

> There isn't one (at least, not past vim 6).

As mentioned on [vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/RLrs0XJxfa4/vzdT27GBCgAJ) by the former maintainer, a very old archive has been put up at [dindinx.net](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdindinx.net%2Ffiles%2Fstuff%2Fvim.tar.gz&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEQWoi79Xyjpvv6qHxwHNh08NiHiQ). The current French maintenance is only [messages, tutorial, man pages, and gvim menus](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/RLrs0XJxfa4/z4J_nSCFCgAJ).

---

<sub>Efforts are underway to find a more up-to-date version, and to possibly host somewhere.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[Some old debian packages](http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vimhelp-fr/). The most recent ones I was able to find.