# How to add translated help to vim?

Tags: help-system

I have vim 8.1 installed.
I want to use the help files translated into french.
The debian package vimhelp-fr is not maintained any more, the compressed tar is unavailable, so I installed the version 6.3 of the debian package.
The files are installed under `/usr/share/vim/vim63/doc/` and their extention is `.frx`

I can't find a way to access them from `:help`

In `/usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim`, I can read:

```
" Vim help file
au BufNewFile,BufRead $VIMRUNTIME/doc/*.txt     setf help
```

So I tried to add the line

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead usr/share/vim/vim63/doc/*.frx     setf help
```

in a file `help-fr.vim` under `~/vim/ftdetect/`, and also directly in `filetype.vim`.

Then I tried to type

```
:help help.frx
```

and

```
:help /usr/share/vim/vim63/doc/help.frx
```

within vim.

No success.
How can access the french files using `:help` to see them like help files?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *very* brief summary from `:help help-translated`, you need to put the files in the `doc` directory somewhere in `'runtimepath'` (I highly suspect `/usr/share/vim/vim63` is not on the runtimepath in newer vims). You also probably need to run `:helptags` to generate the appropriate tags.

You can then:

- set `'helplang'` to your preferred languages (the default is set from the environment, probably using locale)
- force a language like `:help user-manual@fr`
- use `<C-]>` in non-English help files to try to find tags matching that language first

---

Note: [in this highly-related Q](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16015/10604), I discovered that the french help is way out of date, and not actively maintained! If you make improvements, please contribute them back to vim :)