# How are the french spl files produced? Can they be updated?

Tags: spell-checking

Is there any information on how the french spl files are produced?   I notice there is a sug file that downloads via netrw but this does not seem to be available at:

http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/fr/
https://ftp.nluug.nl/vim/runtime/spell
https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime/spell/fr

The latter shows the .aff/.dic files were updated 14 years ago. I have tried to produce newer versions based hunspell .aff/.dic files from both:

https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/dictionnaires-francais (hunspell 5.7)
http://grammalecte.net/download/fr/hunspell-french-dictionaries-v7.0.zip   (hunspell 7.0)

For some reason (with files renamed appropriately):

```
nvim -es +"mkspell! ./fr-classique.utf-8.spl ./dictionaries/classique/fr_FR"
```

succeeds with the version 7.0 hunspell files from grammalect.net, but fails with the older files from libreoffice.  I tried both nvim and vim with various options but was not able to redirect the output. However when running without the 's' switch I can see in the console that with the openoffice files it seems to fail after starting to process (the first word in??) the .dic file. And there are a lot of various 'Unrecognized or duplicate item; Trailing text' errors when processing the .aff file.

Is there something different with the oo files that render them incompatible?

That said the spellchecking quality produced from the fr.utf-8.spl file that I am able to produce from the grammalect hunspell 7.0 files leaves ***much*** to be desired. (no matter what the variant:  classique, reforme1990, toutesvariante.

Thanks for any insight on this.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16015/where-are-the-french-help-files

Comment: There's an issue [on the Vim issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4916), which mentions "Vim does not cope with enough Hunspell features to import it" (referring to the grammalecte.net file). Reading through the issue, getting good support for French might be tricky without improvements to Vim's spell system, but I don't speak French so it's a bit hard to judge.

Comment: Ah...  Thanks.  This is what I suspected.   But still would be nice to find out where that fr-utf-8.sug file comes from and how it is produced.   As the issue above also refers to https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/846 which (supporting hunspell) is problably the long term solution to the poor quality spellcheck in French.